# About Php, MySQL, Magento and Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, ubuntu

I decided to set up a local server in the office using Ubuntu Server 12.04, despite it was my first time setting up a server it went pretty smooth. The LAMP installation is working good. Now, I was given a copy of a web-store made using Magento, so I restored the database in the server, copied all the files and then changed the xml file to give access to the database using the current ip, username and password. But when I tried to access the site this is what I got:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.18.67' (111)

Trace:
#0 /var/www/dev8/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/dev8/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/dev8/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/dev8/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/dev8/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(455): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /var/www/dev8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /var/www/dev8/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /var/www/dev8/index2.php(104): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 /var/www/dev8/index.php(213): include_once('/var/www/dev8/i...')
#21 {main}
```

I deleted the old cache the store had but it didn't work. As you can see in the error trace they were using **Zend Framework**, I've never used it before, so my question is:

- Do I need to install Zend framework on my server? or this error is not related to it?

If not, what else should I do?

I created a folder and a test.php to test the server, it worked. The magento store is in a folder call dev8.

When I type: 192.168.18.67/test/ shows me the files under test and they are accessible.
When I type: 192.168.18.67/dev8/ it keeps loading and nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Following the instructions that @AshleySwatton gave me here are config.xml and local.xml

config.xml:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date/>
        </install>
        <resources>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                    <username>root<username/>
                    <password>******<password/>
                    <dbname>dev8</dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>0</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
            <default_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_write>
            <default_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_read>
            <core_setup>
                <setup>
```

... and it continues but there is nothing relevant that I've seen could be changed.

Here's local.xml:

```
<config>
  <global>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    <!-- <cache>
        <backend>memcached</backend>
        <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
        <memcached>
            <servers>
                <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[80]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
                </server>
            </servers>
            <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
            <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
            <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
            <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
            <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
        </memcached>
    </cache> -->
    <install>
      <date><![CDATA[Fri, 15 Aug 2008 02:46:01 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
      <key><![CDATA[eb40abfff28c11f762fc19172c53c896]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
      <db>
        <table_prefix/>
      </db>
      <default_setup>
        <connection>
          <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                  <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                  <password><![CDATA[******]]></password>
          <dbname><![CDATA[dev8]]></dbname>
          <active>1</active>
        </connection>
      </default_setup>
    </resources>
        <remote_addr_headers><!-- list headers that contain real client IP if webserver is behind a reverse proxy $
                        <header1>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header1>
                        <header2>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header2>
        </remote_addr_headers>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <frontName><![CDATA[data]]></frontName>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <lightspeed>
      <global>
          <connection>
               <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
               <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
               <password><$![CDATA[******]]></password>
               <dbname><![CDATA[dev8]]></dbname>
          </connection>
          <multi_currency>0</multi_currency>
          <request_path><![CDATA[]]></request_path>
      </global>
      <session><type/><path/><servers><localhost><host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host><port><![CDATA[11211]]></port><persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent></localhost></servers><connection><host>localhost</host><username>root</username><password>******</password><dbname>dev8</dbname></connection></session><cache><type/><path/><servers><localhost><host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host><port><![CDATA[80]]></port><persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent></localhost></servers></cache></lightspeed></config>
```

Comment: The Zend library is included with the Magento installation (hence the zend folder in the stack trace).  Looks like you have a typical mysql connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lower-level problem (from what I can tell). Either MySQL isn't running, there's a firewall in the way, you're connecting on the wrong port or maybe the credentials are wrong. You need to do some more troubleshooting.

Comment: Let me answer you by asking you some questions since I'm not an expert:
- I'm able to access remotely to mySQL and add, update or delete whatever I want, that means that mySQL is running, right?
- There's a firewall indeed, but since I'm able to access 192.168.18.67/test means that that's not the problem?

Comment: by the way, so that problem has nothing to do with the fact that Zend is not installed? Do I need it or it should work fine without it? Thanks

Comment: Ensure you updated both local.xml and config.xml with db credentials. Do not install Zend, all zend stuff is bundled in with Magento. Asdwjv says this is not a magento issue per say but a connection issue, so check your credentials in the mentioned files and retry. Manually delete the contents of /magento/var/cache so it can pickup the updated values in the xml files. If that doesn't do it tehn something else must be stopping it from connecting. Is the db on the same machine as the site. If so replace the IP address with 127.0.0.1

Comment: @AshleySwatton I'm gonna check all what you said and I'll get back. Thanks in advance for the help!
By the way, the database is on the same machine as the site, if I change the IP to 127.0.0.1 will I be able to access it from a different PC (locally) using 192.168.18.67 which is the server's IP?

Comment: Yep, you will as the php code gets executed on the same machine as the database. http request comes in and the server connects to the db, generates the html and returns the response (so its the server that does db work not the client). You might need to manually update the base URL's for the site in the db to reflect your IP address in the test environment once the db issue is fixed (If you get redirected to actual live site then this will need to be done in table core_config_data for both web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url).

Comment: @AshleySwatton I updated both local.xml and config.xml with db credentials using 127.0.0.1, also deleted contents of cache, now the error disapeared and the page loads immediately but displays nothing. I changed also both web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url. Value was localhost/dev8/ and I changed it to localhost/dev8:80/ it didn't work with any of those. Any other suggestion I can use?

Comment: should be `http://localhost/dev8/` for both secure and unsecure unless you have ssl certificate installed in which case the secure would be `https://localhost/dev8/`. Check magentos exception and system logs as well as php and www error logs. clear the cache when you make changes. to make it work so that internal users on other machines can access it use `http://192.168.18.67/dev8/`. Ensure cache folder is writeable.